# Correct way to group by month and year?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

I need to group by month (and year) and I was thinking about:

```
GROUP BY CAST(YEAR(tDate) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(tDate) AS NVARCHAR(2))
```

But I found in the web something like:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(tDate), Month(tDate)
```

Both are equivalent? It is better to use the second?

Comment: I'd use the second. If there is an index on `tDate` I'd be annoyed though that even though the index is already in `year,month` order I can't think of any way of expressing this so SQL Server will take advantage of this and potentially use a stream aggregate without a sort

Comment: On a performance point of view, wouldn't that group by using Windows function forces a full scan ? If it's a big table and if there is some where clauses that return only a small part of the data, I would look for a computed column on year and one on month (persistent column).

Answer (score 7):

You should go with the second approach.  All of the string concatenation and type conversion just adds unnecessary CPU overheard to the query.

I can try this out on the Stack Overflow schema.  I'm going to query the user's table, and create a supporting nonclustered index on the date field:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_CreationDate ON dbo.Users (CreationDate);
```

Here's an example of the first approach:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(YEAR(u.CreationDate) AS NVARCHAR(4)) 
        + '-' 
        + CAST(MONTH(u.CreationDate) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Users u
GROUP BY 
    CAST(YEAR(u.CreationDate) AS NVARCHAR(4)) 
        + '-' 
        + CAST(MONTH(u.CreationDate) AS NVARCHAR(2));
```

And [the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJDL3LJlE) and stats:

[image: plan for query 1]

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
Table 'Users'. Scan count 1, logical reads 675

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 203 ms,  elapsed time = 258 ms.
```

Compare that to the second approach:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(u.CreationDate), Month(u.CreationDate), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Users u
GROUP BY YEAR(u.CreationDate), Month(u.CreationDate);
```

Here are [the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By_tTUke4) and stats for that one:

[image: plan for query 2]

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0
Table 'Users'. Scan count 1, logical reads 675

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 125 ms,  elapsed time = 229 ms.
```

As you can see, the string concat / cast approach uses slightly more CPU.  Everything else is the same.

---

By the way, the dbo.Users table only has about 300,000 rows in it.  Going through this same exercise on the dbo.Posts table, which has about 3,700,000 rows in it, the query goes parallel, and the CPU savings for the second approach become much more significant.

So not only is the 2nd approach better in terms of CPU in the general case, it also appears to scale better as data size increases.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2022+ another option is [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

This [addresses a long standing irritation](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/10/t-sql-queries/date-bucket-datetrunc-improve-time-based-grouping) that I have had with grouping by date parts (namely that an index on `date`/`datetime2`/`datetime` will already be ordered by year, year +month, date etc. but this was not previously taking advantage of for this type of case).

The below reads from the index in `date` order and feeds the truncated date (to start of month) into a stream aggregate without any redundant additional sort.

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
tDate DATE INDEX ix_Date
)

SELECT COUNT(*), 
       DATETRUNC(MONTH, tDate)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DATETRUNC(MONTH, tDate);
```

[image]

Comment: what about cases where the query returns multiple years of data?

Comment: @Anthony - what about them? `DATETRUNC(MONTH, GETDATE())` returns `2024-02-01 00:00:00.000`